# WebSphere WAS Express upgrade from 8.5.5.4 to 8.5.5.10

Tags: linux, websphere

I currently have

```
IBM WebSphere Application Server - Express - 8.5.5.4
package - com.ibm.websphere.EXPRESS.v85_8.5.5004.20141119_1746
```

I want to upgrade from 8.5.5.4 to 8.5.5.10

During the process, I have figured out that I need to have minimum 8.5.5.5 installed to upgrade to 8.5.5.10 (not 100% sure if this is correct)

I tried to upgrade to 8.5.5.5 and got the following error

```
 root@CI-TEST-POC AppServer# aal-imcl install com.ibm.websphere.EXPRESS.v85_8.5.5005.20150220_0158 -dataLocation  /var/ibm/InstallationManager/ -repositories http://devci-adrepo.corp.aal.au/ci/im-repo -installationDirectory /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer  -acceptLicense
Repo in use [http://devci-adrepo.corp.aal.au/ci/im-repo]
ERROR: Problems were found with the set of packages and fixes.
  ERROR: Problems were found with the packages and fixes in package group IBM WebSphere Application Server V8.5.
    ERROR: You cannot uninstall the IBM WebSphere Application Server - Express fix which is superseded by the installed package 8.5.5.3-WS-WASProd-IFPI55697.
root@CI-TEST-POC AppServer#
```

Can someone please let me know what am I missing or what is the process to upgrade to 8.5.5.10 using aal-imcl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have 8.5.5.3-WS-WASProd-IFPI55697 that might need to be uninstalled first.

You can first check what you have currently installed using the listInstalledPackages command:

```
imcl listInstalledPackages -installationDirectory /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer
```

After that, try an uninstall of 8.5.5.3-WS-WASProd-IFPI55697 using imcl:

```
imcl uninstall 8.5.5.3-WS-WASProd-IFPI55697 -installationDirectory /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer
```

You can then retry the command to update your 8.5.5.4 to a newer level.

(If you still have issues after the above, contact IBM Support.)

It is possible to update from 8.5.5.4 to 8.5.5.10 directly as long as you have the 8.5.5.10 fix pack in a repository somewhere.

Note also that aal-imcl is not standard part of IBM Installation Manager -- there is a wrapper? -- imcl is what comes with IBM Installation Manager.  You may also want to ensure that your Installation Manager is up-to-date too.  The latest version available is 1.8.5.

Hope these help.

Comment: Thanks ykchang. It worked. On top of this, I had to take a fresh copy of /var/ibm/InstallationManager/  from another instance. Thanks for your help

Comment: Good to hear that.  Do note that it is not advisable to lift /var/ibm/InstallationManager/ from one instance to another unless it is an accurate backup of what you had.